# Why is my Sieve of Eratosthenes giving some composite numbers?

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So, after running my implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, for some cases, it also gives me composite numbers.

Eg.

When the limit of numbers is 10, I get, 2, 3, 5, 7, and 9 too.

When the limit is 30, I get 25 along with the prime numbers.

Why is this? My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

long long n;

int main()
{
    cout << "Till what number to find primes of?" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int m = sqrt(n);
    vector<bool> prime(n+1, true);
    for(int i = 2; i<m; i++)
    {
        if(prime[i])
        {
            for(int k=i*i; k<=n; k=k+i)
            {
                prime[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int j=2; j<=n; j++)
    {
        if(prime[j])
        {
            cout << j << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding a C++ tag to this, since that's what you've used in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are checking for `i < m` rather than `i <= m`, so you never check the square root of 9, of 25 etc.

Change

```
for(int i = 2; i<m; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 2; i<=m; i++)
```